# Is there any way to convert youtube embed URL into Blob Object

Tags: angular, http, video, youtube, blob

First, I'm trying to online any URL convert into blob It's Working Fine Using below Approch.

```
this.http.get(video,{ responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(response => {
           //console.log("response : ",response)
})
```

But, Is there any way to convert the youtube embed URL into Blob. I tried the above approach. **But, It's giving the HttpErrorResponse, statusText: "Unknown Error" status : 0.** Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what do you mean by youtube embed URL?

Comment: Currently, I tried with any youtube URL like => normal URL:  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Au63DyjBQ7k" or embed URL: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Au63DyjBQ7k". But no luck. embed Url means Which is used in an iframe for playing the Video.

Comment: @prakashBhosale Thank you for your response. I tried the way which you putting into the answer. But It's getting the HTTP Failure and status = 0 with using any URL(normal or Embed).

Comment: can you please show me your logic of convert video into blob?

Comment: Here, I did not apply any specific logic. I used only 3 lines which is I mention above. It works for any online Video URL. Inside the video variable passes the Direct URL. But It's not applicable in the youtube URL.